# dynamic grid layout using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am planning to make grid layout based on user input. For example, if user input value '3', 3 x 3 square is put on the page dynamically like Tic-Tac-Toc game layout. I am thinking that flexbox is the good approach for it. However, based on the input value, the width and height of each cell will be different. I have heard that the dimension control by setting .px would not be desirable way. I have  researched a lot of examples, but I can't find a dynamic layout example yet. Do you have some advice about this issue?

The way I have tried is like below. Here, I used bootstrap but I realized that I do not need to use it because gridcss or flexbox have already provided that feature. Anyway, after making html string, I put them in the container but as you expect height is much smaller than width. What I want to do is adjust width and height by myself, what would be a good way to do it? I did not want to set px values directly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        html += '<div class="row">';
        for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
          html += `
            <div class="col-md-1">0</div>`;
        }
        html += "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming part of the issue here is creating cells with 1:1 aspect ratio bound within a playing board.

For this you can use a nifty CSS-trick where you embed the cell within another div that has `padding-top: 100%;`.

`padding-top` is relative to the parent element's `width`, so with a value of `100%` the aspect-ratio will always be 1:1

[Working jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/DendrilT/w90cnmvb/)

Comment: Wow, it can be good solution, thank you so much!! I tried to figure out last night very hard. I put the same width and height for container (display:grid), and then grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr). It gave squares with same width and height. Thank you so much for your solution again.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Please mark my answer as the thread solution if you're happy with the suggestion.